# Unable to display PDF highlights in PySide6, while annotations are visible in web viewer

Tags: python-3.x, pyside, pyside6, pdf-viewer, pymupdf

I am currently working on a Python application using PySide6 to display and highlight PDF documents.
The problem is that when I open the same PDF file in chrome, the highlights and annotations are visible, but when I load the PDF in my PySide6 application, the highlights do not show up.
this is the pdf viewer i am using
[Link](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_pdfwidgets_pdfviewer.html)

[image: Pdf viewer image]

[image: Web image]

I have tried using web view but i was facing an issue of finding current page.

Comment: this is the link of documentation [link](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtPdf/QPdfDocumentRenderOptions.html#PySide6.QtPdf.PySide6.QtPdf.QPdfDocumentRenderOptions.setRenderFlags)

Comment: While the QPdfPageRenderer and QPdfDocument classes provide render functions that allow settings specific QPdfDocumentRendererOptions (which includes annotations), QPdfView lacks supports for *setting* such options. Right now, it seems like the only way to provide such funtionalities is to create your own pdf view using the QtPdf classes and render pages on your own.